# Popups and Combo-Box inside Rowexpander - Extjs 6.0.2

Tags: extjs, extjs6.2

Is there any way to put a combobox inside rowexpander inside grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can place any Extjs component inside rowexpander. It is possible with rowBodyTpl.

Check this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2c7i&view/editor

```
plugins: [
            {
                ptype: 'rowexpander',
                rowBodyTpl: [
                    '<select>',
                    '<tpl foreach=".">',
                    '<option value="">{$}</option>',
                    '</tpl>',
                    '</select>'

                ]
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!